# Single data cannot write twice in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got error "E11000 duplicate key error collection: latestdb1.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "email@g1mail.com" }"

```
const express = require("express");
connectToMongo();

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json())

app.use('/api/auth',require('./routes/auth'))
app.use("/api/notes", require('./routes/notes'));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: A quick search suggests that you have an index enforcing a unique constraint so this appears to be working as intended. What would you like for us to assist with? What have you researched or attempted in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

remove "unique : true" from your model which contains "email" property.